# List all installed packages in Ubuntu using python

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I am using python 2.7.
How do I get a list of all installed packages in python on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `subprocess` module.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('dpkg -l', shell=True)
```